# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity

Tags: java, apache, http, exception, buildpath

Tried everytihng but the solution, I added to buildpath, imported via manifest.mf, but I keep getting this exception.
In build path: commons-codec-1.8.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, httpclient-4.2.5.jar, httpcore-4.2.4.jar. I tried with httpmime-4.0.1 and selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar, but I keep getting this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/httpEntity
    at autorun.Main.main<Main.java:101>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run<Unknown Source>
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run<Unknown Source>
    at java.security.AccesController.doPrivileged<Native Method>
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass<Unknown Source>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: build path != runtime classpath

Comment: @JigarJoshi In general, yes, but doesn't Eclipse automatically ensure those JARs are in the runtime classpath when you execute your project?

Comment: I don't see eclipse mentioned in whole page (except for your comment, and now in my this comment )

Comment: @JigarJoshi I was perhaps reading too much into the use of the [tag:buildpath] tag, which is exclusive to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Understand the difference between these 2 commands:

- `javac -cp [dir/jar] [class].java`
- `java -cp [dir/jar] [class]`

Both need the dependencies on classpath, but one needs it for compiling and the other needs it at runtime.Now as per Javadoc:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

Which basically means: *Everything was okay at compilation/packaging(that is why you have the current Java bytecode!), but at runtime the class(class definition) could not be found.*

Now loosely speaking

```
Build  = compilation + packaging
```

so buildpath `can` be thought of as classpath during compilation. The `NoClassDefFoundError` tells us that the problem occurred at runtime. So that means the required class was present on classpath at compile/build time but was *missing* at runtime.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for help.
I tried to add commons-codec-1.8.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, httpclient-4.2.5.jar, httpcore-4.2.4.jar to classpath, but don't work. What should I add to classpath? (I use Eclipse and I used Run/Run Configurations/Classpath.)

Comment: @Judit try dumping your runtime classpath `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` and see if the jar is available containing class

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the required jars(containing httpEntity and other relevant class ) to your `classpath` while running your program. Build path is used for compiling /building your code but not for execution.